# Remove non-numeric characters including numbers that form a URL

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which is comprised of a set of numbers and a URL.  I only need all numeric characters except the ones attached to the URL. Below is my code to remove all non-numeric characters but it doesn't remove the numbers from the URL.

```
test = '4758 11b98https://www.website11/111'
re.sub("[^0-9]","",test)

expected result: 47581198
```

Comment: Yeah, but removing that would end up dropping all numeric characters. I need all numeric characters except the ones attached to the URL

Comment: You just want to return the numbers from the beginning of the string?

Comment: I have update the example string now to cater to instances of spaces and letters between the numbers. I want to return all the numbers and join all of them as one string EXCEPT the numbers from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

##### original answer

Change strategy, it is much easier to just keep the leading numbers and ignore the rest:

```
import re
test = '47581198https://www.website11/111'
re.findall(r'^\d+', test)[0]
```

Or, using match, if it is not sure that the leading numbers are present:

```
m = re.match(r'\d+', test)
if m:
    m = m.group()
```

Output: `'47581198'`

##### Edit after question change

If you're sure that the 'http://' string cannot be in your initial number.

Then you need two passes, one to remove the URL, and another to clean the number.

```
test = '4758 11b98https://www.website11/1111'
re.sub('\D', '', re.sub('https?://.*', '', test))
```

Output: `'47581198'`

Comment: Thanks for this. This can be an option yes, but I've just updated my example now to show the most difficult instance that I have. Just considering the leading numbers would end up getting just '4758' right?

Comment: @Yel check my update

Comment: Oh this one works quite well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below expression:

```
y=re.compile('([0-9]+)(?=.*http)')
tokens = y.findall(test)
print(''.join(tokens))
```

Comment: What if the expression is `1h23http://...`?

Comment: @mozway you can check my edited answer with this updated answer and given the string by you it provides 123 as output

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is a nice answer, but there are corner cases that make it tricky, try for example `1h23http://example.org/1/protocol=http`

Comment: @mozway Absolutely not. In fact, your input string has given me more clarity to improve upon my solution it's just that in OP's question it was mentioned to have a URL so have not assumed that HTTP can reappear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could match a string that contains https:// or http:// to not capture digits attached to it, and use an alternation `|` to capture the other digits in group 1.

Then in the output, join all the digits from group 1 with an empty string.

```
https?://\S+|(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EGRxBH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fJ5iRE)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"https?://\S+|(\d+)"
s = "4758 11b98https://www.website11/111"

print(''.join(re.findall(pattern, s)))
```

Output

```
47581198
```